# Invalid Qualifier error in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: string, vb6

In a Visual Basic 6.0 program, I have a string sTemp that I want to ensure does not contain a quotation mark. I have the line:

```
If sTemp.Contains("""") Then
```

But when I type the period after sTemp, I don't get anything from intellisense, and when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
Compile error:
Invalid qualifier
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VB6 strings are not objects, so there are no methods on the string variable that you can call.

To test does the string contain quotes you need to use the `InStr` function i.e.

```
if InStr(sTemp, """") > 0 then ' string contains at least one double quote
```

Hope this helps

**UPDATE** *This has nothing to do with the original question*

William, I just thought of this, it is unrelated information that you may find useful.

There are *many ways* to shoot yourself in the foot with VB6.
Among the less obvious is the fact that

```
Dim myCollection as new Collection
```

will have [side effects you could never imagine](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=511763).

**Never DIM something AS *New* CSomething**

Dim your variable, then on a second line, assign it to a new object. Hope this helps.

```
Dim myCollection as Collection
Set myCollection = New Collection
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. First time using visual basic :-)

Comment: I'm not sure how an argumentative diatribe helps here, nor how naive misuse of "As New" has any bearing whatsoever on the question at hand.

Comment: @Bob: Very well, will remove _agrumentative_ portion of diatribe. Added information on _As New_ for Williams benefit as - by the looks of things - he is new to Vb6. It is extra information, but I don't see how it detracts from the portion of the answer that answers the question.

Comment: @Bob: P.S The diatribe helps me, I find it quite cathartic :)

Comment: I'm kinda sorry I missed the diatribe ;-) Picking up VB6 for work. Will keep the dim as new bit in mind; I haven't heard about that one.

Comment: It would probably help if you linked to at least one of the unimaginable side-effects on that last one.

Answer (score 1):

Try `if instr(sTemp, """") > 0 then`