# VBA invalid qualifier with string.copy

Tags: vba

I'm writing a code that loops through the textboxes of a word document. These textboxes contain a picture and a caption. So far, I have written a code that gets the caption from the textbox (which I checked through `MsgBox caption`).

I want to copy the caption, clear the textbox of all content, and then paste the old caption back in (because I'm trying to replace the pictures with an updated one). However, I keep getting an error with `caption.Copy` and have no idea why. It says that caption is an "Invalid Qualifier." I did some digging around online but haven't solved my problem.

This was the most-related thing I found: [Invalid Qualifier error in Visual Basic 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204917/invalid-qualifier-error-in-visual-basic-6-0)

Anyway, here's my code. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub ReplaceImages()

Dim str As String
Dim captionTag As String
Dim imageTag As String
'Dim objShape As Variant Type Mismatch?
Dim fileName As String


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Select directory to match .PNG to figure in document
Set SelectFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With SelectFolder
        .Title = "Select Directory"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo ResetSettings
        sPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

sFile = Dir(sPath & "*png")
Do While sFile <> ""
    fileName = sFile
    MsgBox fileName
    imageTag = BetweenParentheses(fileName)

    For Each objShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes

    If objShape.Type = msoTextBox Then
        Set shapePicture = objShape

       str = objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        If InStr(str, "(") > 0 Then
            captionTag = BetweenParentheses(objShape.TextFrame.TextRange)
            If captionTag = imageTag Then
                If InStr(str, "Figure") > 0 Then

                    Dim firstTerm As String
                    Dim secondTerm As String
                    Dim caption As String


                    firstTerm = "F"
                    secondTerm = ")"

                    Dim startPos As Long
                    Dim stopPos As Long
                    Dim nextPosition As Long
                    nextPosition = 1


                    caption = objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text


                    Do Until nextPosition = 0
                   startPos = InStr(nextPosition, caption, firstTerm, vbTextCompare) - 1
                        stopPos = InStr(startPos, caption, secondTerm, vbTextCompare) + 1
                        caption = Mid$(caption, startPos + Len(firstTerm), stopPos - startPos - Len(firstTerm))
                        nextPosition = InStr(stopPos, caption, firstTerm, vbTextCompare)
                   Loop

                    caption.Copy 'This is where the error is



                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next objShape
sFile = Dir
Loop

ResetSettings:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `caption` variable is a string while the `Copy` method only applies to objects in the Word object model.

You store the text from the `TextFrame` into the `caption` variable:

```
caption = objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```

And then manipulate it inside your loop.

If you want to keep the value of the `caption` variable, then assign the value to another variable:

```
Dim someOtherVariable As String
someOtherVariable  = caption
```

Comment: Why are you using `caption.Copy`? What went wrong using the method in my answer?

Comment: I assigned the value of the caption variable to another variable, and then tried to copy that variable to the clipboard. I got the same invalid qualifier error.

Comment: You don't need to copy the string variable. To put it back into the shape ty using `objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = caption`

Comment: I get it now! Thanks, that make so much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some different between Excel and Word VBA in embedded shapes, but the following should be easy enough to adopt to word:

```
Sub test()
    Dim shp As Shape, s As String
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    s = shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text ' this is a string which doesn't have a Copy method
    Debug.Print s
    'but:
    shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Copy 'copies to clipboard!
End Sub
```

You can double check that the text is in the clipboard by pasting it directly into the immediate window (or wherever).

Comment: Thanks, this copies to the clipboard but I'm only trying to get part of what's in the textbox. This copies both the picture and the caption and I only want the caption...

Comment: I should probably add that the Debug.Print caption works and only prints what I need, it's the next line that isn't working

Comment: In seems that in Excel you need to use `TextFrame2` if you want to access the text using `TextRange`. In Word just delete the "2". In your case keep what you had and just change and use `TextFrame.TextRange.Copy` . I don't see how this would copy any image -- if you just use `Selection.Paste` (I experimented in Word) you just get text rather than a whole textbox pasted. Are you sure that you didn't try `TextFrame.Copy` or even `shp.Copy`? In any event -- Chip is probably correct that you can probably do what you want to do without any copying at all -- simple variable is enough.